# I have a data coming from the api how do I display it in tree form in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

This is the following data that is coming from api
I have to dispaly this data in the tree form

```
 {
    "Customers": {
        "M": {
            "age": 20,
            "email": "m@kuchto.com",
            "AA": null,
            "DD": "555"
        },
        "Hh": {
            "course": {
                "c++": {
                    "duration": 3
                }
            }
        }}
```

I am not sure if I need to use map function inside my render method to iterate and display the data and how will it work along.Can someone let me know if I am doing it right or is there any better way of doing it. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to approach this task. You can create a component yourself to render the `tree` structure or you can use UI frameworks like `Material UI` to do the task for you. I think it's better not to re-invent the wheel here and use the UI framework. For example, `Material UI` has a `Tree` component for `React`. You can sort of implement the structure like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TreeView from '@material-ui/lab/TreeView';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import TreeItem from '@material-ui/lab/TreeItem';

const data = {
  id: 'root',
  name: 'Parent',
  children: [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'Child - 1',
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      name: 'Child - 3',
      children: [
        {
          id: '4',
          name: 'Child - 4',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    height: 110,
    flexGrow: 1,
    maxWidth: 400,
  },
});

export default function RecursiveTreeView() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const renderTree = (nodes) => (
    <TreeItem key={nodes.id} nodeId={nodes.id} label={nodes.name}>
      {Array.isArray(nodes.children) ? nodes.children.map((node) => renderTree(node)) : null}
    </TreeItem>
  );

  return (
    <TreeView
      className={classes.root}
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpanded={['root']}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
    >
      {renderTree(data)}
    </TreeView>
  );
}
```

Another option is to use `npm` packages like [react-simple-tree-menu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-tree-menu). It's easy to implement. It has good documentation and you don't have to rely on a UI framework just to implement a tree view on a component.